# syslog-ng set loglevel/priority to warning or more to be less verbose

Tags: syslog-ng, loglevel

How to run/configure `syslog-ng` to log only above the security loglevel/priority `WARNING`?

I would like to discard `NOTICES` like:

```
Destination timeout has elapsed, closing connection; fd='36'
```

From the docs: (https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.22/administration-guide/17#TOPIC-1209129) I found this:

> The syslog-ng OSE application sends the following message types from
>   the internal() source:
>
> fatal: Priority value: critical (2), Facility
>   value: syslog (5)
>
> error: Priority value: error (3), Facility value: syslog (5)
>
> warning: Priority value: warning (4), Facility value: syslog (5)
>
> notice: Priority value: notice (5), Facility value: syslog (5)
>
> info: Priority value: info (6), Facility value: syslog (5)

But can't find how to set the loglevel to `warning`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `internal()` source of syslog-ng produces internal messages on different hard-coded log levels. `verbose`, `debug`, and `trace` messages can be enabled/disabled with `syslog-ng-ctl verbose|debug|trace --set on|off` .

You can add a filter to keep only warnings and above:

```
filter f_warn { severity(warning..emergency) };

log {
  source { internal(); };
  filter(f_warn);
  destination { ... };
};
```

Comment: Is there any diference using `level` instead of `severity` for example: `filter f_warn { level(warning..emerg); };` ?

Comment: No, level() is just an alias for severity().